# Is it possible to write to HTML data-* using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I can't believe there's no easy-to-find answer for this, and the official [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/data/) only serves to confuse me.

I have a `div` with a `data-` attribute, let's say `data-color`, and I want to change it when the user clicks a button.

I figured I'd do it like this:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('.div-with-data').data('color', 'red')
})
```

But it doesn't work. Is it possible at all to actually write to `data-` like this or is it read only?

Comment: Use `.attr('data-color', 'red')`

Comment: Your code is working fine - it just doesn't update the DOM. jQuery stores `data` attributes in an internal cache object for better performance. You should *always* use `data()` to get and set these attributes, unless there is a specific reason you need it available in the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working fine - it just doesn't update the DOM. jQuery stores `data` attributes in an internal cache object for better performance. You should *always* use `data()` to get and set these attributes, unless there is a specific reason you need it available in the DOM.

```js
alert($('.div-with-data').data('color')); // = green

$('.button').click(function(){
  $('.div-with-data').data('color', 'red');
  alert($('.div-with-data').data('color')); // it's now red
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-with-data" data-color="green">
    Foo
</div>

<button class="button">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me why my asnwer is wrong. Someone downvoted it without explaining I think you are an appropriate person to erase the confusion created inside my head. Thank you very much

Comment: Theres nothing inherently wrong with it, it just doesn't follow best practice. The down vote wasn't me by the way.

Comment: I know you are not the person who downvoted it without explaining, I see how you behave in the community. Thank you for information I will rewrite my whole code with `data()` and use it in future dev. again thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('.div-with-data').attr('data-color', 'red')
})
```

Comment: Of course, I don't know why I didn't think of that. But still, weird that `data()` doesn't work.