# jQuery - Use Check boxes to toggle text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have been working with  jQuery code (source: http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox) and trying to add a toggle function so when clicked, some text will hide/unhide.

I am a bit of a starter at this so not sure if I am going in the right direction.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Button - Checkboxes</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"     href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#check" ).button();
    $( "#format" ).buttonset();
  });
  </script>

<script>
$( "#check1" ).click(function() {
  $( "#text1" ).toggle();
});
</script>

  <style>
  #format { margin-top: 2em; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="format">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check1"><label for="check1">Option 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check2"><label for="check2">Option 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check3"><label for="check3">Option 3</label>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<p id="text1">Hello</p>
<p id="text2">Bye</p>
<p id="text3">Other</p
```

So I have tried to add the .toggle part in here and I can't make it do anything. This might be due to how I have tried to id things - if so how can I do this to make it work?

I will have to add more toggle conditions when I get it working so that:
When Option 1 is selected text1, text2, text3 are all shown
Option 2 is selected only text 1, text 2 are shown
Option 3 is selected only text 2, text 3 are shown.

Let me know if this needs clarification. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

-Thanks

Comment: May be you want to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31259755/jquery-use-check-boxes-to-toggle-text/31259875#31259875

Comment: `$( "#check" ).button();` ... I don't think that will do anything.

Comment: Hi Jadecat, have any of the answers below solved your question? If not, would you care to provide more information/context? If so, please mark one or more answer as useful, and choose one as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would address your question directly with a code snippet, but there are some structure issues in your code that need to be fixed first. The code you have in fact already works, you just need to change the structure of your document a bit.

- Firstly, your `<p>` elements need to be inside the document's `<body>` tag. The way you currently have them (outside the `<html>` element) isn't valid HTML.
- Secondly, your javascript needs to be at the bottom of your body. Javascript is executed as soon as the browser encounters it, so the way your code is currently written, you are trying to use jQuery to select elements that haven't been created yet.

Here is a revision of your code that works:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Button - Checkboxes</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet"     href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">


      <style>
      #format { margin-top: 2em; }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="format">
      <input type="checkbox" id="check1"><label for="check1">Option 1</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="check2"><label for="check2">Option 2</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="check3"><label for="check3">Option 3</label>
      <p id="text1">Hello</p>
      <p id="text2">Bye</p>
      <p id="text3">Other</p>
      <script>
      $(function() {
          $( "#check" ).button();
          $( "#format" ).buttonset();
      });
      $( "#check1" ).click(function() {
          $( "#text1" ).toggle();
      });
      </script>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @Jadecat Glad we could help you with this question! To mark an answer as the accepted answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Answer (score 1):

Short and Sweet code for You.

```
$( "input[id^=check]" ).click(function() {
    textbox = $(this).attr('id').replace("check","text");    
    $("#"+textbox).toggle();
 });
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/58yesddx/)**

Comment: This is the smartest/elegant solution so far. Plus one. But he first should implement advices provided by other answers.

Comment: Alos I have heard that `.data('id')` is best practice here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989832/is-it-possible-to-write-to-html-data-using-jquery/30989864#30989864

Answer (score 0):

update your code as below

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tLzn320u/)

```
<div id="format">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check1" data-id="text1"><label for="check1">Option 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check2" data-id="text2"><label for="check2">Option 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check3" data-id="text3"><label for="check3">Option 3</label>
</div>

<p id="text1">Hello</p>
<p id="text2">Bye</p>
<p id="text3">Other</p>
```

jQuery

```
 $( "input[id^=check]" ).click(function() {
   $( "#"+$( this ).data('id') ).toggle();
 });
```

use data attribute to reference  text element id tag id.